# Location glitching

Tags: pokemon-go

When I am at home opening Pokémon Go to check for Pokémons around my house I'll always find my character walking around the house maybe walk to blocks away from the house and sometimes he even runs so fast to other places then  the game sends me the driving alert. It never happens when I am walking around only happens when I am not moving.

Could I maybe get banned for this if the character is walking too fast? Am I the only one?

**PS:** It's sometimes fun when there is only 100 meters left for a egg. Other than that it's annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're fine. This is the game trying to work with limited GPS signal indoors, doing its best to figure out where it is exactly. You won't get banned unless you visit New York, Paris and London in 10 seconds.

Comment: I once saw a vlogger playing Pokemon Go on a plane. How isn't he banned

Comment: It's not automated as VAC for instance. They do it in waves also the GPS on a plane would show a consistent line of travel and not bluntly jumping all over the planet.